# Redirect in one virtual host file affecting all

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a virtual host file with a redirect in it to force requests for the domain to https.

It seems to work **too** well. I added another virtual host file, and all requests for it (:80) are redirected to the first domain on :443. That is, requests for sub.b.com:80 get redirected to a.com:443. Note that b.com is not on the same server, only its sub domain is.

**a.com**

```
<VirtualHost a.com:80>
    ServerName a.com
    Redirect permanent / https://a.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost a.com:443>
    ServerName a.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/a
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/www.a.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/a.com.key

        <Directory /var/www/html/a>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**sub.b.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.b.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/b
        <Directory /var/www/html/b>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests for `b.com` will be handled by the first `<VirtualHost>` because you have no `<VirtualHost>` for `b.com`.

You only have a `<VirtualHost>` for `sub.b.com`.

So `b.com` is handled by the first `<VirtualHost>` for that IP/port, since none is assigned to handle it and that is the way it defaults.

Comment: b.com is on a different server. How do I resolve it requiring a virtual host?

Comment: It doesn't require a virtual host if it's on a different server. Are you saying that `sub.b.com` gets redirected to `https://a.com`?

Comment: Yes, clarifying in the description

Comment: Perhaps you have the redirect cached in your browser. Also you shouldn't say `<VirtualHost a.com:80>` you should use `<VirtualHost *:80>` or specify the IP address in place of the star.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, why do you say you added another virtual host file? Why aren't they all in the same file? Perhaps the second one isn't being read.

Comment: I prefer to keep each host in its own file in sites-available. Apache imports all .conf files from that folder. Going to a different browser didn't change the results. Going to change the virtualhost entry as you recommend.

Comment: You might try putting the `sub.b.com` virtual host in the same file as `a.com` just to test in case that is what is causing the problem, and they are not all being loaded for some reason. The behaviour you are seeing is because it is defaulting to the first virtual host for that IP/port that it found since no other was assigned to it, so it seems it isn't being read. Don't forget to clear cache before each test, or use something like `httpie`.

Comment: It was the VirtualHost entry! As soon as I changed that back to *:80 (and cleared the browser cache) all was well! Thanks very much!